# Как узнать индекс элемента списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

**Python 3.7.7**

```py
mylist = ['Daria', 'Anton', 'Vlad', 'Kirill']
```

Надо узнать индекс элемента `'Vlad'`. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `mylist.index('Vlad')`

Comment: Евгений, спасибо!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как узнать индекс элемента

```
mylist.index("Vlad")
```

Comment: ответ не полный,- добавьте внятное описание задокументированой функции

Comment: если индекс не найден